# Enable the background restriction and allow app to run in background for long running operation?

Tags: android

Unable to by pass battery saver app of multiple manufacturer for no restriction to run background operation.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to be sure your operation would run fine on a service, in the background, use a foreground service instead:

https://developer.android.com/guide/components/services

If you want to run some background task based on some conditions, use WorkManager:

https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/workmanager

Comment: I am already running my service as foreground service but the problem is  my service runs  until user clear from task manager after clearing task manager my service gets killed on the other hand if in phone like mi if i allow app with no restriction in battery saver my service keeps running  as long as i want

Comment: There is no reason the foreground service would be killed, unless something is using a huge amount of RAM. Please make a sample, minimized project, so that we could check it out.